# DependencyProperties: PropertyChangedCallBack only called once

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I created a control, derived from `Canvas`, that should plot a live diagram, given values that are passed via a binding to a DependencyProperty. The simplified version is this:

```
public class Plotter : Canvas
{
    public float Value { get { return (float)GetValue(ValueProperty); } set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); } }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(float), typeof(Plotter),
        new PropertyMetadata(0f, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChangedCallBack)));

    public static void ValueChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Plotter plotter = (Plotter)property;
        plotter.Value = (float)args.NewValue; //<-- Removed this line to get it to work

        // Actually draw the value into the canvas geometry
        plotter.PlotValue(plotter.Value);
    }
}
```

I bound the control like this:

```
<mystuff:Plotter Value="{Binding MyViewModelProperty}" Height="50" Width="200" />
```

My ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and calls `PropertyChanged` correctly. If I bind `MyViewModelProperty` to a textbox, it correctly updates every time. Only if I bind it to my own control, my `ValueChangedCallBack` is only called once as the page is loaded, and then never again.

What am I not seeing here? Thanks for any help!

**Solved:** I dont have to set the `Value` explicitly in the callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the property Value on the callback for the property Value changing. That doesn't make much sense in any case. But is that locally set value overriding the binding value, causing your binding to no longer be set on the dependency property?

Comment: Ahhh, that was the issue. Thanks a lot! I just removed the line that sets ``Value`` explicitly, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to set the Mode of your binding to TwoWay?

Comment: no, it should just be OneWay binding. The ViewModel spits out a new value, and my control should be notified and plot it into the canvas geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Should you not be using DependencyProperty.Register instead of DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached?

Comment: Oh, sorry, just a copy and paste mistake. Originally, it was ``DependencyProperty.Register``. I changed it, just to be sure. It doesnt work with both versions.

Comment: Nicholas W's answer seems to be on the right track. Remove plotter.Value = (float)args.NewValue; from the callback method and everything should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks!